# Mex compilation macro

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I wish to include a certain header file only when my code is compiled via the mex command in Matlab. If it's compiled directly with Visual Studio I do not want it included.

Is there a macro that can help with that?

I'd like to do something of this sort:

```
#ifdef MEX_COMPILE_FLAG
#include "mexDependent.h"
#end
```

Comment: When "it's compiled directly with Visual Studio", is VS creating a *.mex file, or a standalone *.exe?

Comment: @aschepler standalone

Comment: I found that if I take care to include "mex.h" before anything else, mex_h macro can be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the macro `MATLAB_MEX_FILE` for this.  To get mex.h to work properly, this macro must be defined if and only if the compiled object will eventually be linked into a mex file.  So the `mex` command makes sure to always define it when it calls the compiler.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this manually:

```
mex -DMEX_COMPILE_FLAG ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `mex` just calls some other compiler without reliably setting a preprocessor macro. However, if your Matlab build script does set `MEX_COMPILE_FLAG`, then your proposal will work, except that `#end` needs to be `#endif`.